# Run ANT without asking user for input?

Tags: ant, command-line-interface

I have an ant script with several `input` targets that have defaults set. How can I execute ant from the command line or shell such that it will just accept the defaults and not prompt?

**Update** Wow, I was thinking this was going to be a quick one. Another way to ask the question would be is there any way I can specify the properties when ANT is called instead of through `input` prompts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a couple of suggestions, I'm sure there are other alternatives too.

The simplest option is to just take input from `/dev/null`:

```
ant < /dev/null
```

(I think on windows you can use `NUL` to do the same.)  That will result in defaults being used.

But perhaps a more useful approach is to supply a properties file that sets the values you want for each of the prompted inputs using an [inputhandler](http://ant.apache.org/manual/inputhandler.html).  The following will read input values from the file `properties.txt`.

```
export ANT_OPTS=-Dant.input.properties=properties.txt
ant -inputhandler org.apache.tools.ant.input.PropertyFileInputHandler
```

Each entry in the properties file consists of a line like

```
prompt_string=value
```

You add a property for each input prompt.  If different inputs use the same prompt, this might get tricky, or just plain not work.

There are other [inputhandlers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/inputhandler.html) too.

The other possibility (as you mention) is to set each of the properties that are prompted for on the Ant command line using `-Dprop.name=value`.  Then Ant will use those supplied values and not try to prompt.  You'll see this sort of thing in the log in that case:

```
[input] skipping input as property prompt.one has already been set.
```

Comment: The dev/null solution repeats the input question over and over!

Comment: @Adam - oh dear - what OS is that?  Works for me on OS X...  Also, what version of Ant?

Comment: RH 2.16 and ANT 1.8.1 Nothing too out of the ordinary

Comment: though I ended up using my solution I'm going to accept yours since A. you have good info and ideas that others can use and B. I think it's silly to accept my own over another viable option

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to specify the property using `-Dpropertyname=propertydefaultvalue` when calling ANT.